# com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException when just connecting the database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, database-connection

Im trying to connect to my sql database with the following command in java

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
```

where url is

```
jdbc:mysql://www.SampleSite.net:2222/DatabaseName
```

While i just execute the command above, i get the following error

```
`com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (5526600 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.

at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:605)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2412)
```

...

What i should do? I only tried to connect, therefore the query isn't such long.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

On the database server, you must change the mysql configuration file. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html

You should not need to do anything on the client at all.

Comment: the path of file if any one needs it, Windows: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6/my.ini and Change 'max_allowed_packet' value.